# ios 10 application with sensitive data in memory during execution

Tags: ios, security, operating-system, heap-memory, appstore-sandbox

Is it possible to read the data in the memory from a running application. i.e is it possible to dump the memory of a running ios application and be able to know the data in variables.

As we have memory edit on windows OS, which is used to change the variables of the running application, is it possible to do the same or at least read the data from the variables.

For example: if there is a variable with sensitive data(a string) which is encrypted and the user can decrypt the data only by providing password. Is it possible for the same user to be able to get the encrypted form of data from the memory during app execution(so that he can brute force or some other technique to decrypt data without password)

P.S : The encrypted data will be given through network, so it wont be hardcoded into the application.

Please let me know if there are any other vulnerabilities.

By running the application in Sandbox is it safe anyhow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apps on iOS are sandboxed, and cannot access each others' memory or data (unless explicitly shared via various methods).

Data stored on disk can be further protected by configuring a strict Data Protection class, such as [`NSFileProtectionComplete`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsfileprotectioncomplete). (Although you should carefully evaluate which data protection class is appropriate for your app - the most strict class prevents data access when the device is locked, even if your app is running in the background.)

However, all of this assumes that the device's security is still intact (as designed).

In the past, jailbreaks have been available for iOS that enable device owners to bypass the various security mechanisms in place in the OS. On a jailbroken device, all bets are off - if a device owner can bypass iOS's security features, they may be able to trivially access the contents of your app's memory.

It is also possible that a security vulnerability in the operating system or support libraries could enable arbitrary memory access, or remote code execution within the context of your app.

What this all boils down to is:

**You are ultimately providing the user the data, on *their* device.**

You cannot ensure 100% security against a determined attacker, and you should not ever assume that it is impossible for someone to completely modify the behavior of your app on their device (including accessing all the data you give them).

But you can make it more difficult by:

- Minimizing the amount of unencrypted data that is stored in memory at one time, and the duration it's kept unencrypted.
- Ensuring that access checks are performed on your server - not by trusting the client to only decrypt the data that the user is allowed to access. (For example: have the client authenticate the user with the server, and have the server only provide the data that that user is allowed to access.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. Here my assumption is that iphone is not jail broken. In that case I believe that data is safe in the memory. Please correct me if I am wrong and yes I request for user to authenticate with the server.